# undefined method for gallery id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following the Railscast tutorial for CarrierWave (#253). However immediately noticed that the creator had already made the gallery model/controller. This was never shown in the video or explained in a different tutorial. I have been creating the gallery and have just about everything working except for this page /photos/new?gallery_id=3 which is suppose to show me a field to upload a photo.

I can go to /galleries and it will list all Galleries created. I can then click on one of the galleries and be taken to /galleries/3 which will present links to Add, Remove, and View Galleries.

The error I am receiving is "undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass". NoMethodError in PhotosController#new is title of page.

Can someone take a look and point me in the right direction? Thanks.

photos_controller:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new(:gallery_id => params[:gallery_id])
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(paramas[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to @photo.gallery
  end
end
```

_form.html in views/photos

```
<%= form_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :gallery_id %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= f.file_field :image %>
            </p>

            <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

new.html

```
<% title "New Photo " %>

<%= render 'form' %>

<p><%= link_to "Back to Gallery", @photo.gallery %></p>
```

routes.rb

```
Dating::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
  get "/profile/:id" => "users#show"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :galleries
  resources :photos

  root to: 'users#new'
  root to: 'galleries#index'
```

Comment: The error should refer to a specific file and line number - please post the relevant sections of code.

Comment: what is the `title`?? Is it helper method?

Comment: The parameters request is "{"gallery_id"=>"3"}". The framework trace is at http://pastie.org/6355545. The title doesn't need to be there code it. I have had issues getting that to work so I'm going to take that down actually. But even with it removed that does not change the error. The actually full url to add a image is not being created. I need to add more to my define new which I don't know what.

Comment: Is it valid statement `redirect_to @photo.gallery`?? I have never seen using like this.. It should be `routes path`. Same in `link_to` also. For adding correct routes do `rake routes` it will list routes for you and use the same.